Start consuming kafka messages after Envoy Sidecar becomes ready
I have an application running is Prod in Kubernetes, and during the deployment I get bunch of errors.
15:12:03.495 [xx-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1925)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition xxxxxxxx-15 at offset xxxxx. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:331)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:283)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.fetchRecords(FetchCollector.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.collectFetch(FetchCollector.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:666)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:590)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:874)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1600)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1296)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 19222
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:345)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:152)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:321)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:639)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:386)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:408)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1312)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1131)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1060)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1690)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1614)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:281)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:371)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:840)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:813)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:294)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:417)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:342)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

I checked the envoy sidecar logs, Kafka consumers start consuming messages even before envoy sidecar is ready and since consumer is dependent on kafka schema registry, kafka fails to deserialise the payload to desired schema.
Is there a way we can delay message consumption until envoy is ready? Here we can not utilise readiness probe from kubernetes since kafka consumers start consuming messages earlier.
Can someone share their experience what could be done in this situation that effectively solves the problem.

If you have Kubernetes version >= 1.28.x you can enable the feature gate SidecarContainers, it adds a functionality to schedule sidecards as init containers, which means that sidecars are always ready (if they declare a valid readiness probe of course) before the main containers start. This is what Istio does with the envoy proxy for example.

I'm wondering if a "startupProbe" for your Kafka consumer could solve your problem.
startupProbe:
exec:
  command:
    - sh
    - '-c'
    - >
      command_to_check_envoy_is_ready


Thanks for the answer. This would control the HTTP traffic but kafka traffic does not wait for readiness probe. I don't think this can help.

Instead of using the startupProbe command I used this pattern in helm configs and it fixed the issue. Thanks.
